# How to change the background colour of a .png image of a chart from grey to white in R?

Tags: r, image, png, hue

**Issue:**

I have a `PNG image file` that has been exported from a spectrogram (**Spectogram 1**) I want to change the grey colour background to a white background so it looks crisper.

I have never dealt with images before in R. Is there any way that I could transform the background of Spectrogram 1 to white and convert the wiggly whistle-type contents and axis to a bold black format to look more like a neater version of **Spectrogram 2**? I tried using software called `PhotoScissors` [here](https://photoscissors.com/editor/354476763/uE_KrsI-F) and I nearly created the image that I desire but the x-axis disappears (**Spectrogram 3**).

If anyone can help, I would be grateful. I've looked online and I cannot find figure it out.

Many thanks in advance.

**Spectrogram 1**

[image]

**Spectrogram 2**

[image]

**Spectrogram 3**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

R might not be the best tool for this task. Though R can interface with the `ImageMagick` command line tool, which may have functions that will help.

How many images are you converting?

An other tool to consider is `GIMP`, which has many filters (similar to Photoshop) to consider in your image cleaning.

I applied the following filters to your image as an experiment:

- Deinterlace  - to remove the vertical bands
- Threshold - to convert from grayscale to black and white

[image]

Comment: Hello M.Viking. Thank you so much for answering my question. Your output is definitely better than Spectrogram 1, which is great. I've been looking nearly all evening and I found a software called Photoscissors (see Spectrogram 3). This is the effect that I wanted to achieve but the x-axis has disappeared. I will give GIMP a try too. Is there a way to delete the background in GIMP as I did with Photoscissors? Many thanks if you can help.

Comment: I only have five of these to do